# Angular js : can not read value from dictionnary

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't read a value from dictionary. The value is an object "commandStateTypes" to retrieve the state of default

```
 1:
    commandStateTypes: {
    defaut interne: null
    defaut liaison: {date: "2016-05-30T01:01:04", value: true, name: "defaut liaison", idComponent: 1}}
    component: {id:1 ,idInstallation:1,name:"Commande1"}
```

#### Controller:

```
$scope.GetStateByComponents = function() {
  var res = false;
  Object.keys($scope.componentsHelper).forEach(function(key) {
    angular.forEach($scope.componentsHelper[key].commandStateTypes, function(value, key) {
      if (value.name == null) {
        res = true;
        $scope.componentStates[{
          name: value.name,
          state: res
        }];
      }
    });
    return res;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use spaces in keys. "defaut interne" -> "defaut_interne"

```
 1:{
        commandStateTypes: {
             defaut_interne: null
             defaut_liaison: {
                 date: "2016-05-30T01:01:04", 
                 value: true, 
                 name: "defaut liaison", 
                 idComponent: 1
             }
         },
         component: {
             id:1 ,
             idInstallation:1,
             name:"Commande1"
         }
   }
```